# How does Angular AOT compilation result in fewer "Fewer asynchronous requests"

Tags: angular, angular2-aot, aot, angular-aot

While reading the [Angular AOT section in the docs](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#why-compile-with-aot) it states that AOT compilation results in

> "Fewer asynchronous requests"

. The reasoning behind this is because:

> "The compiler inlines external HTML templates and CSS style sheets
>   within the application JavaScript, eliminating separate ajax requests
>   for those source files."

But I cannot see how this is true as when you run a build with angular using AOT and another build not using AOT you end up with the exact same files.

```
index.html
main.js
polyfills.js
runtime.js
styles.js
vendor.js
```

So how is this going to result in "Fewer asynchronous requests" if both builds produce the same number of files?

Comment: for prod builds the vendor bundle is integrated into your main bundle. I guess you are doing something wrong,  share screenshots if possible

Comment: Whats your angular version and what command you executed for prod build?

Comment: Angular cli replaces `templateUrl` with `template` through transformer https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/63a9bd464f29972f7522158ebff92d440cd5ce97/packages/ngtools/webpack/src/transformers/replace_resources.ts#L97-L102 If you will create ng application from scratch and leave it as templateUrl then you will catch those requests